# I want to concatenate two python arange, but i only obtain the first arange

Tags: python, numpy

I want to concatenate two arange in python, but I only obtain the first arange

```
import numpy as np  
a = np.arange(3,6, 0.5, dtype = float)
b = np.arange(10, 7, 0.5, dtype = float)
c=np.concatenate((a, b))
print(c)
```

```
[3.  3.5 4.  4.5 5.  5.5]
```

I Dont know why? someone can help me, please!
I could like obtain this

```
[3.  3.5  4.  4.5  5.  5.5  10  9.5  9.  8.5  8.  7.5]
```

Comment: Your array `b` is empty, because start and stop are in reverse order or step has the wrong sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the step to -0.5 for array b as its going from 10 to 7.

```
import numpy as np  
a = np.arange(3,6, 0.5, dtype = float)
b = np.arange(10, 7, -0.5, dtype = float)
c=np.concatenate((a, b))
print(c)

In [130]: c                                                                     
Out[130]: 
array([ 3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,  5.5, 10. ,  9.5,  9. ,  8.5,  8. ,
        7.5])
```

Currently you get an empty array in b :

```
b = np.arange(10, 7, 0.5, dtype = float) 
b                                                                     
array([], dtype=float64)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)